# UTF-U em Python ainda retorna caracteres especiais errado

Tags: python, string, utf-8, encode, utf8-decode

tenho uma string em Python e quero printa-la:

```
prompt1 = """
Feliz Natal 
Já É Quase Cinco Da Manhã
Guerra
Dança
Hortelã e Açúcar
Pesque Pague
"""

print(prompt1.encode('utf-8', errors='replace').decode('utf-8'))
```

O problema é que não estou conseguindo fazer com que a string seja printada no meu prompt, separadas da forma que está na string e com os caracteres especiais, o print retorna os caracteres especiais da seguinte forma: �

Answer (score -1, accepted):

É provavel que seja a codificação padrão do teu terminal.
Tente definir a codificação antes de imprimir a string, segue exemplo:

```
import sys

sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')

prompt1 = """
Feliz Natal 
Já É Quase Cinco Da Manhã
Guerra
Dança
Hortelã e Açúcar
Pesque Pague
"""

print(prompt1)
```

o resultado é oque você espera:
[Imagem da saída do Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GzGP.png)

Comment: É exatamente isso querido!! Muito obrigado!

Comment: qual o motivo do down vote, sendo que está certo e atendeu a pergunta do autor?
Muito sem sentido, namoral